# При вертикальном touch на слайдере, не прокручивается страница

Tags: jquery, ipad

Всем добрый день!

Проблема касается планшетов, в частности iPad.

Есть слайдер **[jquery.contentcarousel.js](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/16/circular-content-carousel/)**, кроме этого подключен плагин **[touchwipe](http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library)** для управления с помощью жестов на мобильных устройствах.

Слайдер горизонтальный. При левом **touch**, слайдер прокручивается влево, при **правом** вправо. Если в момент вертикального скролла страницы мы перехватываем слайдер, то все работает корректно, но когда страница "стоит" и мы вертикальным тачем по слайдеру пытаемся прокрутить страницу, страница не прокручивается.

Вот код:

```
$("#ca-container").touchwipe({
  wipeLeft: function(event) { 
    if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
    cache.isAnimating   = true;
    aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
  },
    wipeRight: function(event) { 
     if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
     cache.isAnimating  = true;
     aux.navigate( -1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
  },
  wipeUp: function() { alert("up"); },
  wipeDown: function() { alert("down"); },
  min_move_x: 20,
  min_move_y: 20,
  preventDefaultEvents: true
});
```

*Что необходимо прописать для событий wipeUp и wipeDown, чтобы страница прокручивалась?*

Спасибо.

Comment: (@Rubaxa)Константин, большое спасибо. Все отлично! Очень выручили!

Вашему ответу - v + 15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подключите [zepto.touch.js](https://raw.github.com/madrobby/zepto/master/src/touch.js)  (скоприуйте его себе) после jQuery.
Вот небольшой пример использования — http://jsfiddle.net/6HTYy/7/

Comment: Забыли знак вопроса в двух строках:

    preventDefault(e, config[dx > 0 ? 'wipeUp' : 'wipeDown']);
    // и
    preventDefault(e, config[dx > 0 ? 'wipeLeft' : 'wipeRight']);

Comment: Так работает или нет? :]

Comment: К сожалению нет.

Comment: Жаль, просто очень проблематично так править, да и iPad нет под рукой, сейчас попробую через эмулятор посмотреть.

Comment: @RubaXa, спасибо огромное за помощь. Если будет время и необходимый инструментарий под рукой, посмотрите пожалуйста более подробно.

Заранее благодарю.

С уважением, Александр

Comment: @RubaXa, Вы не смотрели, что не так со скриптом?

Comment: Ох, сорри, совсем забыл, постараюсь вечером глянуть.

Comment: @RubaXa. Константин, большое спасибо. Буду ждать.

С уважением, Александр

Comment: @Astor, обновил овет.